# Convert JS string into HTML component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any way I can render the code in the form of string into the React Component, I have tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML, react-parser, and React Markdown but none of it is working.

```html
cons data = ` <script>
  var myVar1 = setInterval(function() {
    myTimer1();
  }, 1000);

  function myTimer1() {
    var d1 = new Date();
    document.getElementById("clock1").innerHTML = d1.toLocaleTimeString();
  }
</script>
<h3 id="clock1"></h3>`
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: data}} />
```

``

Comment: Use a proper React component to begin with instead

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: `d1.toLocaleTimeString()` returns a string and does not need to be set as HTML. Just use it like `<div>{d1.toLocaleTimeString()}</div>` or the likes in your JSX/TSX template.

Comment: What I am trying to do is pretty weird this this entire code will be in string 
`<script>
  var myVar1 = setInterval(function() {
    myTimer1();
  }, 1000);

  function myTimer1() {
    var d1 = new Date();
    document.getElementById("clock1").innerHTML = d1.toLocaleTimeString();
  }
</script>
<h3 id="clock1"></h3>`

and I want to convert it into the HTML component ? Like what we do with setDangerousHTML 


`<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: '<p>First &middot; Second</p>'}}></div>
`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry brother on my part, now the post is clear to you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
const [dateTime, setDateTime] = useState(600); // i set sec
useEffect(() => {
    if (dateTime == 0) { // when sec left 0
      setDateTime(0);
    } else {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setDateTime((leftTime) => leftTime - 1);
      }, 1000);
      return () => clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [dateTime]);
<div className="time-count">
   {new Date(dateTime * 1000).toISOString().substr(14, 5)} //this will show sec you can set date if you want 
</div>
```

you can use this format and customize this code.

Comment: This is not what I was looking for, I wanted to render the JavaScript String into HTML component.